# Foreach loop shows wrong information

Tags: php

I have super weird question, I'm grabbing data from the database and if there is 6 or more entries, then it kinda starts showing wrong information. Data on 6th or more row(s) will show transaction_id as 0 for some reason, but it's actually in the database. After doing `echo $key` it even shows it there in the array.

//Edit

**Solved, but one more question
Seems like I was able to fix the issue using `===`, but the problem is now how can I use same thing is database query? Because I have a line which gets all `transactions` where `transaction_id` = 0, but it somehow gets that 6th transaction.**

Here is my code:

```
<? foreach($transactions as $key): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?=$key['id']?></th>
        <th><?=$key['type']?></th>
        <th><?=$key['amount']?></th>
        <th><?php if($key['transaction_id'] == 0){echo 'Transaction not completed'; } else { echo $key['transaction_id'];}?></th>
        <th><?=$key['user']?></th>
        <th><?=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $key['time']);?></th>
    </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Requested sample from `$transactions`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 80681
            [3] => 80681
            [transaction_id] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [4] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [time] => 1492790068
            [5] => 1492790068
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81085
            [3] => 81085
            [transaction_id] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [4] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [time] => 1492856512
            [5] => 1492856512
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81212
            [3] => 81212
            [transaction_id] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [4] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [time] => 1492857095
            [5] => 1492857095
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 81053
            [3] => 81053
            [transaction_id] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [4] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [time] => 1492858665
            [5] => 1492858665
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [0] => 5
            [type] => withdraw
            [1] => withdraw
            [address] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [2] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [amount] => 20000
            [3] => 20000
            [transaction_id] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [4] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [time] => 1492865145
            [5] => 1492865145
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [0] => 6
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 120888
            [3] => 120888
            [transaction_id] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [4] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [time] => 1492942795
            [5] => 1492942795
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 80681
            [3] => 80681
            [transaction_id] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [4] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [time] => 1492790068
            [5] => 1492790068
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81085
            [3] => 81085
            [transaction_id] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [4] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [time] => 1492856512
            [5] => 1492856512
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81212
            [3] => 81212
            [transaction_id] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [4] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [time] => 1492857095
            [5] => 1492857095
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 81053
            [3] => 81053
            [transaction_id] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [4] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [time] => 1492858665
            [5] => 1492858665
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [0] => 5
            [type] => withdraw
            [1] => withdraw
            [address] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [2] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [amount] => 20000
            [3] => 20000
            [transaction_id] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [4] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [time] => 1492865145
            [5] => 1492865145
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [0] => 6
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 120888
            [3] => 120888
            [transaction_id] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [4] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [time] => 1492942795
            [5] => 1492942795
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 80681
            [3] => 80681
            [transaction_id] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [4] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [time] => 1492790068
            [5] => 1492790068
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81085
            [3] => 81085
            [transaction_id] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [4] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [time] => 1492856512
            [5] => 1492856512
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81212
            [3] => 81212
            [transaction_id] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [4] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [time] => 1492857095
            [5] => 1492857095
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 81053
            [3] => 81053
            [transaction_id] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [4] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [time] => 1492858665
            [5] => 1492858665
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [0] => 5
            [type] => withdraw
            [1] => withdraw
            [address] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [2] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [amount] => 20000
            [3] => 20000
            [transaction_id] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [4] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [time] => 1492865145
            [5] => 1492865145
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [0] => 6
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 120888
            [3] => 120888
            [transaction_id] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [4] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [time] => 1492942795
            [5] => 1492942795
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 80681
            [3] => 80681
            [transaction_id] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [4] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [time] => 1492790068
            [5] => 1492790068
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81085
            [3] => 81085
            [transaction_id] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [4] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [time] => 1492856512
            [5] => 1492856512
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81212
            [3] => 81212
            [transaction_id] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [4] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [time] => 1492857095
            [5] => 1492857095
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 81053
            [3] => 81053
            [transaction_id] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [4] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [time] => 1492858665
            [5] => 1492858665
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [0] => 5
            [type] => withdraw
            [1] => withdraw
            [address] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [2] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [amount] => 20000
            [3] => 20000
            [transaction_id] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [4] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [time] => 1492865145
            [5] => 1492865145
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [0] => 6
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 120888
            [3] => 120888
            [transaction_id] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [4] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [time] => 1492942795
            [5] => 1492942795
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 80681
            [3] => 80681
            [transaction_id] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [4] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [time] => 1492790068
            [5] => 1492790068
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81085
            [3] => 81085
            [transaction_id] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [4] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [time] => 1492856512
            [5] => 1492856512
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81212
            [3] => 81212
            [transaction_id] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [4] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [time] => 1492857095
            [5] => 1492857095
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 81053
            [3] => 81053
            [transaction_id] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [4] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [time] => 1492858665
            [5] => 1492858665
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [0] => 5
            [type] => withdraw
            [1] => withdraw
            [address] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [2] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [amount] => 20000
            [3] => 20000
            [transaction_id] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [4] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [time] => 1492865145
            [5] => 1492865145
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [0] => 6
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 120888
            [3] => 120888
            [transaction_id] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [4] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [time] => 1492942795
            [5] => 1492942795
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 80681
            [3] => 80681
            [transaction_id] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [4] => 748d167d779892468f00b1f846bf6c296d69335ae3fd4b17510a506ed82cffac
            [time] => 1492790068
            [5] => 1492790068
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81085
            [3] => 81085
            [transaction_id] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [4] => 207604fd8c7e9d2d6a8d80a24f34ab1cd9e5a3de44aa3efbaacf186d89d7f3d9
            [time] => 1492856512
            [5] => 1492856512
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [2] => 1LoVYNdVfJPGuA6DKQEeHhMM9ivRjdZkKh
            [amount] => 81212
            [3] => 81212
            [transaction_id] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [4] => 483b537623961ab68e04f41bf2a7e56aa4eb7a49cfc8d860d555d60fd6db3c2e
            [time] => 1492857095
            [5] => 1492857095
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 81053
            [3] => 81053
            [transaction_id] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [4] => 42d7c459e6d15d69d59884284f0933c74915e3ec5a1ac7a40c19548daca3677a
            [time] => 1492858665
            [5] => 1492858665
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [0] => 5
            [type] => withdraw
            [1] => withdraw
            [address] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [2] => 1PQwKUHBTUzYB62pwyYXkNFD8SGxp4anAk
            [amount] => 20000
            [3] => 20000
            [transaction_id] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [4] => 9d6429d71d2dbd7658d36dd72c1b4aef761949cd393a18fd360edc875d8602c7
            [time] => 1492865145
            [5] => 1492865145
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [0] => 6
            [type] => deposit
            [1] => deposit
            [address] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [2] => 1531LxjQgH7AMXN1UptZYUEvP4puEyQixa
            [amount] => 120888
            [3] => 120888
            [transaction_id] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [4] => db5e7bbaa8df754d6a16e4b42d48de6d8a476c70017ba8c550926e9eabb6875d
            [time] => 1492942795
            [5] => 1492942795
            [user] => name
            [6] => name
        )

)
```

Comment: can you try print the complete print & check then by 
`echo '<pre>';
print_r($transactions);`
Paste some sample here.

Comment: Please  show what's inside the $key of you 6th entries

Comment: I have edited my first post.

Comment: Seems like I was able to fix the issue using `===`, but the problem is now how can I use same thing is database query? Because I have a line which gets all `transactions` where `transaction_id` = 0, but it somehow gets that 6th transaction.

Comment: this `if($key['transaction_id'] == 0)` is buggy. if `$key['transaction_id']` starts with letters then it will be `true`. This is non-strict comparision issue. Your last transaction_id starts with `db`.

Comment: So why does you compare a string with an integer?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
$key->id
$key->type
....
```

if this didn't work, please print_r() to show your array content

The query to get id = 0:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE `transaction_id` = 0';
```

Your $transactions print_r() shows duplication, try check you transactions query if it running correctly